# Logstash Grok Pattern that matches after 7th character only

Tags: linux, logstash, devops, logstash-grok

I want to parse my logs with grok pattern.

This is my sample log file, which has 7 `|*|` characters in every log.

`2022-12-15 01:11:22|*|639a7439798a26.27827512|*|5369168485-532|*|3622857|*|app.DEBUG|*|Checking the step |*|{"current_process":"PROVIDE PROBLEM INFORMATION","current_step":"SUBMIT_MEMO","queue_steps":}|*|{"_environment":"test","_application":"TEST"}`

I am creating fields with grok pattern, but at the end I am trying to pick only last JSON part after 7th `|*|{"\_environment":"test","\_application":"TEST"}` in every log and parse it with JSON filter in Logstash.

How can I get only JSON object after 7th `|*|` object in every log?

Comment: use [dissect](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html) rather than grok. Much easier as it doesn't require to use regexes

Comment: Whoever set up logging with a separator like that should be sent off to that prison in French Guiana.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grok {
    match => [ "message", "(?<notRequiredField>(?:.*?(\*)+){6}.*?((\*)+))\|%{GREEDYDATA:requiredField}" ]
}
mutate {
      remove_field => [ "notRequiredField" ]
}
```

[image: Grok debug]